# ACF no rows found using wordpress advanced custom field plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

hello experts i have been trying to retrieve data from fields that i created 
[image]

the field name is "ddw" and its repeater and
[image]

its subfield op1 and it has lots of rows [image]

but i am still not able retreive any row by using this code

```
<?php 
require_once 'wp-load.php';
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';
include_once 'wp-content/plugins/acf351/acf.php';
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows(get_field('ddw')) ):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows(get_field('ddw')) ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
       echo the_sub_field('op1');

    endwhile;
else :
    echo 'no rows found';
endif;
?>
```

and it finds no row . i want all rows from every posts and particularly i want http links to put on array and loop through it . i have put this script in wp directory its not theme or template folder. please help me where i am doing wrong .thanks in advance

Comment: I would use `echo get_sub_field` or `the_sub_field` not `echo the_sub_field`

Comment: i tried but still its 'no rows found' just so you know i am not trying to get one post s meta_value i am tryin to get all posts subfield ' op1'  rows.

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert, but I'm familiar with the ACF Repeater plugin. I also notice you probably need to get rid of the get_field on 'ddw'... i.e. 
if( have_rows('ddw') ):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('ddw') ) : the_row();

Comment: git-e-up is right, directly put 'ddw' in both have_rows()

Comment: i tried but its still showing no row found . i think have_rows supposed to show the partiucular post id 's subfield rows but i am trying to show from all posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code to work, it should look like this. (replace $post_id with your post id variable)

```
<?php
require_once 'wp-load.php';
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';
include_once 'wp-content/plugins/acf351/acf.php';
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('ddw' , $post_id) ):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('ddw', $post_id) ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
       echo get_sub_field('op1');

    endwhile;
else :
    echo 'no rows found';
endif;
?>
```

You can find code samples here for all scenarios like without loop or for all posts with post ID.
Try
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/